# RequestFactory exceptions for [Auto bean frozen] edited (mutable) Proxy when just shooting a read query

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Let me just put the question in code:

```java
RPCRequest request = ClientFactory.getRPCRequest();
VenueProxy venue = request
      .create(VenueProxy.class);

venue = request.edit(venue);
venue.setId(121);//Trouble Maker line of code... comment it will make things go smooth
venue.setVersion(0);//helper line otherwise get the exception version is null

request.readVenueById(121).fire(new Reciever<VenueProxy>(){

    public void onSuccess(VenueProxy venue){
         ....
         ....
    }
 }
```

Now, all I am doing here is firing a request for a read query. When I fire the request there is no reference to the newly created and editable proxy Venue, but this is going to give me this exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The AutoBean has been frozen
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.checkFrozen(AbstractAutoBean.java:195)
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.setProperty(AbstractAutoBean.java:270)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.ClientPropertyContext$Setter$.call$(ClientPropertyContext.java)
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.ClientPropertyContext.set(ClientPropertyContext.java:137)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$3.visitValueProperty(AbstractRequestContext.java:910)
at com.xxxxxxxxxx.shared.VenueProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.traverseProperties(EtmVenueMasterProxyAutoBean_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_EntityProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_ValueProxyCategory_com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_BaseProxyCategory.java:356)
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.traverse(AbstractAutoBean.java:166)
at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.accept(AbstractAutoBean.java:101)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.processReturnOperation(AbstractRequestContext.java:879)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.processReturnOperations(AbstractRequestContext.java:1215)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.access$7(AbstractRequestContext.java:1185)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:347)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$5.onTransportSuccess(AbstractRequestContext.java:1108)
at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.DefaultRequestTransport$1.onResponseReceived(DefaultRequestTransport.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor179.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I am curious about this behavior of `RequestFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call edit after create. Create is for creating new objects as I assume you're doing here.

Edit is for editing already existing objects...

Comment: Yet, it's no issue calling `edit()` on an editable proxy, it's then a no-op.

Comment: Even if I do not call edit() on the new created proxy, it throws the same stack of exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7341 (which i'm not sure is actually a bug)

On the server-side, you'll have two objects with the same ID, i.e. representing the same entity, which RequestFactory doesn't handle nicely (it should probably throw on the server, rather than let the client fail at decoding the response).

Answer (score 0):

The request keeps track of the objects it handles, this is how it can send only the changed data between the `edit()` and `fire()` methods.

Having already a bean with the same id in the same request can pause problems. Why don't you just create a new request for that `readVenueById()` call?